# Tensorflow gives 0 results

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am learning Tensorflow from this github
https://colab.research.google.com/github/instillai/TensorFlow-Course/blob/master/codes/ipython/1-basics/tensors.ipynb#scrollTo=TKX2U0Imcm7d
Here is an easy tutorial

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.constant([[1, 1],
                 [1, 1]])
y = tf.constant([[2, 4],
                 [6, 8]])

# Add two tensors
print(tf.add(x, y), "\n")

# Add two tensors
print(tf.matmul(x, y), "\n")
```

What I expect is

```
tf.Tensor(
[[3 5]
 [7 9]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32) 

tf.Tensor(
[[ 8 12]
 [ 8 12]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

However, the results are

```
Tensor("Add_3:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32) 
Tensor("MatMul_3:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Are you using TensorFlow 1? It seems eager execution is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not mean that the values of the tensors are zero. `Add_3:0` and `MatMul_3:0` are just names of the tensors and you can only use `print` in Eager Execution to see the values of the tensors. In `Graph` mode you should use `tf.print` and you should see the results:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1, 1],
                [1, 1]])
y = tf.constant([[2, 4],
                [6, 8]])

print(tf.add(x, y), "\n")
print(tf.matmul(x, y), "\n")

# Graph mode
@tf.function
def calculate():
  x = tf.constant([[1, 1],
                  [1, 1]])
  y = tf.constant([[2, 4],
                  [6, 8]])

  tf.print(tf.add(x, y), "\n")

  tf.print(tf.matmul(x, y), "\n")
  return x, y
_, _ = calculate()
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[3 5]
 [7 9]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32) 

tf.Tensor(
[[ 8 12]
 [ 8 12]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32) 

[[3 5]
 [7 9]] 

[[8 12]
 [8 12]]
```

Without `tf.print`, you will see the your output from the function `calculate`:

```py
Tensor("Add:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32) 

Tensor("MatMul:0", shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

See this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/basics#graphs_and_tffunction) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I still got the original results even I copy and paste your code.

Comment: @user18191392 Did you copy the code and run them in google colab? If you did .. restart your environment and run the code again.